Can a type that has an object format have a conditional type as a value based on another index of itself?
I have searched in a lot of ways but I am not able to find more information about conditional typing, I am trying to create a type called ChatItemMessage and it has 2 indexes, type and value.
This is the current code:
type ChatItemMessage = {
    type: ChatItemMessageType;
    value: ChatMessage | ChatDate;
};

enum ChatItemMessageType {
    Date = "date",
    Message = "message",
}

type ChatMessage = {
    id: number;
};

type ChatDate = {
    date: string;
};

What I am trying to do is conditionally set the type of value based on the value of type:
export type ChatItemMessage = {
    type: ChatItemMessageType;
    value: (ChatItemMessage['type'] extends ChatItemMessageType.Message ? ChatMessage : ChatDate);
};

This is not working, I also tried (and other variations):
export type ChatItemMessage<T extends ChatItemMessageType> = {
    type: T;
    value: (T extends ChatItemMessageType.Message ? ChatMessage : ChatDate);
};

In my code I am then doing:
declare const data: ChatItemMessage[]
data.map(
  message => message.type === ChatItemMessageType.Date ?
    message.value.date : // error!
    //            ~~~~ <--   Property 'date' does not exist on type 'ChatMessage'.
    message.value.id.toFixed() // error!
    //            ~~ <--   Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ChatDate'.
);

What I want is for message.value to be ChatMessage because I already checked if message.type === ChatItemMessageType.Message, but the IDE is always saying it is ChatDate.
The idea is for the IDE and any dev to know that if type = ChatItemMessageType.Message then value = ChatMessage, else (in this case) it will be ChatDate, so new errors should show up if the dev has the wrong type in mind at runtime.
I am not even sure if it can be achieved or not. If you need more info, let me know!

Looks like you want a discriminated union; conditional types and generics don't help you here, or at least not any more than just writing out the union to start with.  See this approach in the TS playground, and please [edit] the code example to show a valid [mre] where we can all see the effects of your original definition and any suggested answers (so we can verify "the IDE is always saying it is ChatDate"); that is, replace pseudocode with an actual example. If my suggestion meets your needs after that [edit] I could write an answer; if not, what's missing?

I cannot add extra code, as I am getting values from a function, I just do const { data } = await fetchMessages();, and data is ChatItemMessage[] (would be then iterating data.map((message) => message.type === ..... the current code in there). I think the union is what I need, it is just horrible to write it as a union, but it works! I have to leave the office in a few minutes, that is why I cannot dedicate more time to this. Could you write the union as the solution so I mark it as the working answer, please?

"I cannot add extra code" You can write that code just like this, which I just threw together from your comment. Do you want me to do the [edit] for you since you're... um... leaving? And why is it "horrible" to write the union? How is that union any more horrible than the examples with conditional types and generics? There are possible ways to compute the union from some more intuitive type, maybe like this, depending on your use case. I'm happy to write an answer but ideally you'd respond first.

If I have extra indexes to also make dynamic, it starts to look very cumbersome to write the possible variations (in this example it is 1-to-1), but the second example you shared looks super complex for what I want to achieve (I really don't want to use generics as generics has nothing to do here, it was just a try). Other languages solve this pretty easily, that is why I find it "ugly" to be a union and not have a more direct and intuitive way of doing it, but I play by the rules, I really prefer the union. Could you edit it the question and make it work for your standards as I am not sure

Without specific examples of these other languages I'll have to take your word for unions being "horrible" and "ugly". I will disengage on this, though, and just post the union in my answer.

For this to work you need ChatItemMessage to be a discriminated union, where each member of the union corresponds to one of the possibilities for type/value pairings, so that type can be used as a discriminant property. Like this:
type ChatItemMessage =
  { type: ChatItemMessageType.Date; value: ChatDate; } |
  { type: ChatItemMessageType.Message, value: ChatMessage; }

Once you do that your code will work as written:
data.map(
  message => message.type === ChatItemMessageType.Date ?
    message.value.date : // okay
    message.value.id.toFixed() // okay
);

Playground link to code
